# How to find element next to another element?

Tags: python, selenium, xpath

Is there a way to find an element next to another element as shown in the example below? I'm trying to retrieve the word "Daily" by locating the words "Frequency of Update" first. I think an XPath would be the only way but I'm not sure how to get to it since its not a child element.

image: (https://i.stack.imgur.com/ELjbl.png)

Comment: Please don't link us to images, post your code here as a text.

Comment: And what have you tried?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this xpath:

```
//*[contains(text(),'Frequency of Update')]/ancestor::td/following-sibling::td
```

This will first locate the element having innerHTML/text 'Frequency of Update' in the DOM, then locate 'td' element from all its ancestors, and then locate the 'td' element that is its sibling element, which has the 'Daily' text

Comment: Thanks for the reply, it threw an error unfortunately

Comment: eight years later this worked as a solution for what I need to grab - thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can find elements like this:

```
element = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//td[//*[contains(text(),"Frequency of Update")]]')
next_element = element.find_element_by_xpath('./following-sibling::td')
```

If you want to find another element by located element,

> Xpath should start with ' . '

Answer (score 0):

If it's the element's sibling you should use the following xpath:

```
/following-sibling::td


element = <the element you retrived by locating "Frequency of Update">
element.find_element_by_xpath('/following-sibling::td')
```